# How do I pass "..." (variable-length arg list), unchanged, through my function to another?

Tags: c

**Old client code:**

```
printf("foo: %d, bar: %s.\n", f, b);
```

**What I'd like to replace that printf (& 100's others like it) with:**

```
my_printf(ctrl1, ctrl2, "foo: %d, bar: %s.\n", f, b);
```

**Implementation of my_printf**

```
void my_printf(CtrlT1 c1, Ctrl c2, char* fmt, ...) {
/* Do stuff with c1 & c2 */
   fprintf(log, fmt, **WHAT_GOES_HERE**);
}
```

**What I've tried so far**

It seems like there ought to be a simple, direct way to pass the list of arguments associated with `...` through to fprintf.  I tried `fprintf(log, fmt, ...);` but the compiler complains, "syntax error before '...' token".

I also tried:
`va_list ap;`
`va_start(ap, fmt);`
`fprintf(log, fmt, ap);`

The call with the va_list compiles and even runs without coring, but what's being passed to printf is plainly not the same thing as what was passed into my function as `...`, as may be judged by the output (representation of non-printing char).

If push comes to shove, I could probably walk through the contents of the va_list by brute-force but that seems stupid.  Is there no simple token or syntax to pass that `...` through?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't a general solution, but for the stdio functions, look at the ones that start with the letter `v`, such as [`vfprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/vfprintf/). They take a `va_list` as their last parameter, instead of the `...`.

```
void my_printf(CtrlT1 c1, Ctrl c2, char* fmt, ...) {
    /* Do stuff with c1 & c2 */
    va_list ap;
    va_start (ap, fmt);
    vfprintf (log, fmt, ap);
    va_end (ap);
}
```